# how to use DataAnnotations in desktop application

Tags: entity-framework, validation, data-annotations, modelstate, modelmetadata

When we are using `EF` (f.e.) via `MVC`, we can use `ModelState.IsValid` to detect a `model` can pass `DataAnnotations` metadata or not. But how can I use `DataAnnotations` metadata in a desktop (win-forms / wpf) application?

**More:**

In fact, I want to create an object same as `ModelState` (a dictionary that can save properties and messages associated with each). Then, wrap the `DAL` by a `validation-layer`, in `VL` use metadata to validate models, that the `VL` can be used in any project. I know I should use reflector, but I haven't any experience. Thanks to any help and suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using EF 4.1/4.1 dbcontext, it has a built in validation API that can check Data Annotation rules as well as IValidatableObject.Validate. I'm not quite sure that I understand your goal, but if it is to have the validation in the data layer then you can just use what's built in. (Here's an overview http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg193959).

If you want your own validator that is separate from the data layer, then look at the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations namespace for methods and other logic you can leverage to do your own validation.

Comment: The same question, what if I'm not using EF in my app at all? Just want to validate properties of some class? Please, check my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12044509/how-to-use-validationattribute-for-user-input-in-options-pages