# How to use ValidationAttribute for user input in options pages?

Tags: c#, validation, attributes, data-annotations

I'm writing a Visual Studio extension. I have a C# class representing an options page. An option is represented by a public property, like this:

```
public class OptionsPageGeneral : DialogPage
{
  [Range(1, 100)]
  [Category("Misc")]
  [DisplayName("Integer option")]
  public string IntOption { get; set; }
  ...
}
```

[image]

I'm trying to use the [`RangeAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.COMPONENTMODEL.DATAANNOTATIONS.RANGEATTRIBUTE%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION=V4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true) [validation attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationattribute.aspx) to restrict user input. However, for the given code, user still can input any value, not only from [1; 100] range.

I've seen lots examples of ValidationAttribute usage, but all for ASP.NET MVC projects. Is it true this attribute is only applicable in that context?

Anyway, how can I validate user input done in options page? I know I can simply override the property `set` method, but validation attributes require much less code to write and can be reused for the similar properties.

Answer (score 0):

I dont have idea on how to use options page, but you can use a regular expression if you want a range between 1-100 instead of `Range`.

```
  [Category("Misc")]
  [DisplayName("Integer option")]
  [RegularExpression(@"[0-9]{2}")]//This will only allow you to enter only 2 digits
  public string IntOption { get; set; }
```

Comment: From the documentation: "Specifies that a data field value in __ASP.NET__ Dynamic Data must match the specified regular expression". This is again only for ASP.NET.